# How to write a config file for my ensemble model using triton-inference-server

Tags: inference, serving, ensembles, tritonserver

I can't write the config.pbtxt file for my ensemble model.

I'm using two models, a classifier and a segmentation model, for ship detection. The input image is passed through the classifier model, and then I receive two results: a positive number for images with ships and a negative number for images without ships. I only want the images that return positive results to go through the segmentation model.

So, with this requirement, can I write a config file or should I use a different platform for inference and serving the model with these specifications?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.